# How I change the pages link in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, renaming

I've created a page in my WordPress site called "About Me". Then I deleted it. Then I created it again. Now it's shows in the link like this `www.mywebsite.com/about-me-2`.

I want to remove number `2`. I tried renaming the permalink but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remove the already existing page in "TRASH". Then try to create the page. It will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The old page still exists in the trash. You have to go find it and permanently delete it (or rename it). Afterwards you can return the new page to just `/about-me`.